# Laravel job was unable to complete foreach iteration

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

I have a scheduler that runs a job to process an array of 400 objects and I am using foreach loop to iterate the array and perform calculations to each object. However I noticed that the iteration has never been completed.
When it reaches somewhere between 100 - 110th iteration, instead of proceeding to the next iteration, the job is repeated instead, and it starts to iterate from index 0 of the array.

I tried this on my local machine, and it works well and it successfully iterated the whole array and executed all the codes, but never works on a ubuntu server.

```
public function handle()
{
    try {
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            //do something
            //compare something

            $someGroups = $object->certainProperty;

            foreach ($somegroups as $group) {
                //do some calculation and comparison
            }

            $members = $object->certainMembersArray;

            //insert members to DB
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //log exception
    }
}
```

The funny thing is, it never get into the catch block and logs any error or exception, making it hard to debug. At first I suspect it is a memory issue so I have increased the memory, but it didn't make any difference.

Could someone suggest what I can do to investigate the issue further?

UPDATE:

1. Schedule only runs once a day

Comment: Not enough information to help? ... how often does the schedule run? ... Locally, there may only be 400 objects, but how many when run on the Ubuntu server? ... Nested loops take a longer time to process, can anything be done to group some of the object information beforehand to reduce the processing?

Comment: Figure out how long it takes to hit the failure point. If it's [about 60 seconds, that's the default Laravel timeout](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout), at which point the worker exits and the job is (potentially) retried later.

Comment: @PaulT. schedule only runs once a day.

Comment: @ceejayoz spot on, yeah it's timeout issue, Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your job is timing out on the server. Try changing the timeout value on a queue or the job itself. Local machines are usually faster than the small instances/droplets.

You can set the timeout value while starting the queue as below,

> Default timeout is: 60 sec

```bash
$ php artisan queue:work --timeout=120
```

Or you can add the timeout in the job,

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Jobs;
 
class ProcessObjectsJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * The number of seconds the job can run before timing out.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 120;
}
```